# Pagination with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I created a custom post type named "noticias" and duplicated archive.php with name archive-noticias.php. Everything works but when pagination actived, don't work page 2, 3....

I use plugin "T5 Page to Seite" for change "page" slug with "pagina" slug.

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Page to Seite
 * Description: Ersetzt <code>/page/</code> durch <code>/seite/</code>.
 * Author:      Thomas Scholz <info@toscho.de>
 * Author URI:  http://toscho.de
 * License:     MIT
 * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 't5_page_to_seite' ) )
{
register_activation_hook(   __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , 't5_flush_rewrite_on_init' );
add_action( 'init', 't5_page_to_seite' );

function t5_page_to_seite()
{
$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->pagination_base = 'pagina';
}
function t5_flush_rewrite_on_init()
{
add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules', 11 );
}
}
```

And add this line to .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/(.*)/page/(.*) /$1/pagina/$2
```

I'm trying check every posts of stackoverflow and WordpressAnswers but don't work. please, help me.

MONKEYMAN REWRITE ANALYZER RESULTS

http://www.vektorlab.com/rewrite.html

here my custom post type in functions.php

```
function crear_tipo_noticias() {
$labels = array(
'name'               => _x( 'Noticias', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
'singular_name'      => _x( 'Noticia', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
'menu_name'          => __( 'Noticias', 'text_domain' ),
'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Noticia Padre', 'text_domain' ),
'all_items'          => __( 'Noticias', 'text_domain' ),
'view_item'          => __( 'Ver Noticia', 'text_domain' ),
'add_new_item'       => __( 'Añadir Noticia Nueva', 'text_domain' ),
'add_new'            => __( 'Añadir', 'text_domain' ),
'edit_item'          => __( 'Editar Noticia', 'text_domain' ),
'update_item'        => __( 'Actualizar', 'text_domain' ),
'search_items'       => __( 'Buscar Noticias', 'text_domain' ),
'not_found'          => __( 'Noticias no encontradas', 'text_domain' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Noticias no encontradas en Papelera', 'text_domain' ),
);

$rewrite = array(
'slug'                => 'noticia',
'with_front'          => true,
'pages'               => true,
'feeds'               => true,
);

$args = array(
'label'               => __( 'noticia', 'text_domain' ),
'description'         => __( 'Noticias relacionadas con Tuppersex', 'text_domain' ),
'labels'              => $labels,
'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
'hierarchical'        => false,
'public'              => true,
'show_ui'             => true,
'show_in_menu'        => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
'menu_position'       => 5,
'menu_icon'           => site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/images/logo.png',
'can_export'          => true,
'has_archive'         => 'noticias',
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'query_var'           => 'noticias',
'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
'capability_type'     => 'post',
);

register_post_type('noticias', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'crear_tipo_noticias', 0);
```

My archive-noticias.php loop is...

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Try [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) and add the result to your question.

Comment: Do you register the post type _after_ the new pagination rule?

Comment: Did you include `'has_archive' => true` and `'rewrite' => array( 'pages' => true )` when registering your Custom Post Type? Explained: (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Comment: i put 'has_archive' => 'noticias' and 'rewrite' => $rewrite. I must change it?

Comment: @toscho , I change that and still not working... :(

Comment: @toscho i edited my question with creation of custom post type "noticias" in functions.php

Comment: You have to register the pagination rule earlier than the post type. And post types should **never** be registered in a theme.

Comment: @toscho , and how can register post type if not in functions.php? with types plugin for example? I can delete noticias from functions.php and types and create after... is good fot you?

Comment: Just write a special plugin, and hook into `wp_loaded`

Comment: @toscho ok, too for my knowledge. thanks anyway. I will use default pagination_base "page" and i will search a programmer for this (with money). If you can do it for money will be great. how much?

Comment: you don't *have to* move your post type registration code into a plugin, it will work fine and without error if defined in a theme. it's only *recommended* that post types be registered in a plugin, so they exist regardless of the active theme and survive a theme update.

Comment: Really, i apreciated your help, but i need someone who fix this. You know someone? StackExchange have some site for work?

Comment: Problem solved! delete plugin and .httaccess line and install WP htaccess Control Plugin. Change pagination base to "pagina" and work! really thanks for all @toscho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! delete plugin and .httaccess line and install WP htaccess Control Plugin. Change pagination base to "pagina" and work!